# Python matching various keyword from dictionary issues

Tags: python, regex, pandas, keyword, keyword-search

I have a complex text where I am categorizing different keywords stored in a dictionary:

```
    text = 'data-ls-static="1">Making Bio Implants, Drug Delivery and 3D Printing in Medicine,MEDICINE</h3>'

    sector = {"med tech": ['Drug Delivery' '3D printing', 'medicine', 'medical technology', 'bio cell']}
```

this can successfully find my keywords and categorize them with some limitations:

```
    pattern = r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'

    [cat for cat in sector if any(x in re.findall(pattern,text) for x in sector[cat])]
```

The limitations that I cannot solve are:

1. For example, keywords like "Drug Delivery" that are separated by a space are not recognized and therefore categorized.
2. I was not able to make the pattern case insensitive, as words like MEDICINE are not recognized. I tried to add (?i) to the pattern but it doesn't work.
3. The categorized keywords go into a pandas df, but they are printed into []. I tried to loop again the script to take them out but they are still there.

Data to pandas df:

```
    ind_list = []
    for site in url_list:
        ind = [cat for cat in indication if any(x in re.findall(pattern,soup_string) for x in indication[cat])]
        ind_list.append(ind)

    websites['Indication'] = ind_list
```

Current output:

```
Website                                  Sector                              Sub-sector                                 Therapeutical Area Focus URL status
0     url3.com                              [med tech]                                      []                                                 []          []         []
1     www.url1.com                    [med tech, services]                                      []                       [oncology, gastroenterology]          []         []
2     www.url2.com                    [med tech, services]                                      []                                        [orthopedy]          []         []
```

In the output I get [] that I'd like to avoid.

Can you help me with these points?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding to point 3, can you give sample code how you setup the keywords into pandas df ?

Comment: See my analysis result (some hints) as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give you some hints here the problem that can readily be spot:

1. *Why can't match keywords like "Drug Delivery" that are separated by a space ?*  This is because the regex pattern `r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'` does not match for a space.  You can change it to `r'[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+'` (added a space after `9`) if you want to match also for a space.  However, if you want to support other types of white spaces (e.g. \t, \n), you need to further change this regex pattern.
2. *Why don't support case insensitive match ?*  Your code fragment `any(x in re.findall(pattern,text) for x in sector[cat])` requires `x` to have the same upper/lower case for BOTH being in result of `re.findall` and being in `sector[cat]`.  This constrain even cannot be bypassed by setting `flags=re.I` in the `re.findall()` call.  Suggest you to convert them all to the same case before checking.  That is, for example change them all to lower cases before matching:  `any(x in re.findall(pattern,text.lower()) for x.lower() in sector[cat])`  Here we added `.lower()` to both `text` and `x.lower()`.

With the above 2 changes, it should allow you to capture some categorized keywords.

Actually, for this particular case, you may not need to use regular expression and `re.findall` at all.  You may just check e.g.   `sector[cat][i].lower()) in text.lower()`.  That is, change the list comprehension as follows:

```
[cat for cat in sector if any(x in text.lower() for x in [y.lower() for y in sector[cat]])]
```

### Edit

**Test Run with 2-word phrase:**

```
text = 'drug delivery'
sector = {"med tech": ['Drug Delivery', '3D printing', 'medicine', 'medical technology', 'bio cell']}
[cat for cat in sector if any(x in text.lower() for x in [y.lower() for y in sector[cat]])]

Output:       # Successfully got the categorizing keyword even with dictionary values of different upper/lower cases
['med tech']

text = 'Drug Store fast delivery'
[cat for cat in sector if any(x in text.lower() for x in [y.lower() for y in sector[cat]])]

Ouptput:    # Correctly doesn't match with extra words in between 

[]
```

Comment: #SeaBean thanks for the hints. Yes, I solved the insensitive issue. The space thing still is not working, meaning that a dictionary value like "Drug Delivery" matches for "Drug" or "Delivery" and is not stringent enough,

Comment: @Steven This is exactly the idea in my paragraph "Actually..." that you can test for eg. `'Drug Delivery' in text` so that you can check for the whole phrase (2 words) in the target string (called text or soup_string in your code.

Comment: @Steven  Slightly amended the sample code of list comprehension in the bottom of my answer.  This should better demonstrate what I said.

Comment: I see, but also with that I obtain the same results, and it matches single words in the target string.

Comment: You missed out one comma between the 2 strings `'Drug Delivery' '3D printing'` in your dictionary,

Comment: Ok, thanks for noticing it. However, that's not the problem, I have also another dictionary with other keywords, and when values have space in between words it recognizes the single words.

Comment: Ok, if there can be variable spaces between 'Drug' and 'Delivery' rather than you have to match 'Drug Delivery' as a phrase, then it's another story.  This kind of requirement is relatively less seen.  You sure you have this requirement ?

Comment: If you are using my latest code, i.e. the code with `y.lower() for y in sector[cat]`, you shouldn't match for single word for phrases having one space in between words.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it works. I'm going to accept your answer, just wanted to ask you if you have an idea for point 3) in my question.

Comment: @Steven, I didn't answer you point 3) because by the codes you show for pandas, it's still unclear what's the structure of the DataFrame.  So, I tried to let you get the list you assign to the pandas column filled up with contents first and see if it solve the problem.  I just noticed that you used incorrect variable to assign the the pandas column. You used `ind` instead of `ind_list` that has accumulated matches in the loop.  So, if the last loop does not give any match in the list `ind`, you are assigning an empty list created in last loop to the pandas column outside the loop.

Comment: @Steven, the indentation (2 spaces) of the line of code assigning to pandas column is unclear whether it is inside the loop or outside.  If inside, you are assigning the whole column (instead of just a row) with `ind` every time in loop.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I corrected it, but it is correct in my original code. And yes, there is no indentation when I create a new pandas column, so it's outside the loop. I think the problem is not in this part, the issue is when I return the categorization output it's in square brackets, and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @Steven  In order to add a pandas column with a list, you have to see what structure you want the column to be.  Currently, your codes set the column to have all rows in the pandas column with the same value (the final list `ind_list` accumulated by the loop).  So, what layout you expect the pandas column to be ?  Please post also some sample data of the whole DataFrame so that we can see how to fit into the overall DataFrame structure.

Comment: I updated my question with my current output. Hope it is more understandable like that. The current output is what I want to have, except for [] . Thanks.

Comment: @Steven, it's still not clear enough. There is no column named `Indication` in your sample data.  As you have tested with small data that my latest code works to extract values into the list `ind`, the problem should be lying in other parts of your codes. Suggest to do a divide-and-conquer test to start with one website that should have some matches and then check for values extracted into `ind` then trace your program to see why its values can't go into the dataframe.

Comment: I forgot to change column name, but it doesn't matter. My values go in the dataframe as I showed, the only problem is that they are surrounded by square brackets, like [med tech], where I want just med tech. I'll figure it out, thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @Steven Great to hear you are almost done!  For what you mentioned you get [med tech] instead of just 'med tech', I think it is because your extracted result in each loop iteration is in `ind` which is a list (hence [...] for it is a list).  If you want to just get string, you can concatenate the strings stored in the list `ind` before appending to `ind_list`.  For example, use codes like:  `ind_text = ', '.join(ind)` and then `ind_list.append(ind_text)` to replace `ind_list.append(ind)`

Comment: yep, that was it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`findall` is pretty wasteful here since you are repeatedly breaking up the string for each keyword.

If you want to test whether the keyword is in the string:

```py
[cat for cat in sector if any(re.search(word, text, re.I) for word in sector[cat])]
# Output: med tech
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. It seems working better, but it matches single words like "Drug" or "Delivery" in the text when in the dictionary I want to find only "Drug Delivery".

Comment: Can you add your test case? This text doesn't match anything: `text = 'data-ls-static="1">Drug</h3>'`

Comment: I updated the text and dictionary. In the text you can find "Bio Implants", in the dictionary one of the value is " bio cell". In this situation it matches the key med tech because it found "bio", but in reality I wanted to match the exact value "bio cell" if any. In this case it should not match anything.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a different approach other than regex,
I would suggest `difflib` when you have two similar matching words.